# How to know in which line SSIS failed to parse the data from a flat file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a flat file from which I am importing the data to a DB using SSIS. When the SSIS is failing it is just reporting that a particular column has failed importing. But to be more precise I want to know at which line in the flat file the error has occurred so that I can know where to search in the flat file.

**Example:**
Consider a flat file which has the following columns Name, age, Date. Assume that the file has 100 rows. But if SSIS failed at a certain row say 80 while processing the column Date. I am getting the error saying,

**The "component "Derived Column" (19)" failed because error code 0xC0049063 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "DATE" (33)" specifies failure on error.** 
By this I am able to understand that column date has some non-numeric value. But how to know at which line SSIS failed (In this case it is Line:88)

I have to know this because I have large files so I am not able to understand where the error came while parsing.

Can anyone tel me what is 19 in "Derived Column" (19)" and what is 33 in "DATE" (33)" that I got in the error.

Comment: The numbers you reference (19 and 33) are lineage ids. It is the mechanism SSIS uses to keep track of a column throughout a data flow regardless of what name is associated to them.

Comment: Also, if you would be so kind as to review your [outstanding questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/967638/amarnath?tab=questions&sort=newest) and upvote helpful answers, mark questions resolved by checking the outline of a green checkmark or provide updates to the questions, the community of stackoverflow appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a short description of what we do. First we have staging tables for all of our imports that include a rowid. We have two of them, one with the raw data and one with the cleansed data.  Then we have an exception table that records the name of the file we are processing, the data, the rowid of the row that was sent to the exception file, a reason for the exception and the client generated id for the record if there is one (we generally require one but it may not be true for you) . Your needs may vary as to what to put into the table. The first dataflow is the one that transfers the data to the processing table after doing all the cleansing steps.

Now after every step that might have exceptions to pull out, we put the following on the failure path (the red arrow vice the green one coming out of a task)), a derived column task to get the information we want like filename and exceptionreason and data and then a destination connection to the exception table to actually insert the data.

Finally we have an execute SQl task after the dataflow to determine if there were too many exceptions or exceptions that should kill the whole process. Only after it has passed that step do we do another data flow to insert to the prod tables.

Now what does all this complexity get you? First you can easily see the differences between the cleaned and the orginal data if there is a data issue after the load. This tells us if the data that was sent was incorrect (99% of the timne this is the case but we need to prove it to the client) or if the way we cleansed it was incorrect. Next we know exactly which things did not pass the processing and we can easily generate a list for our data provider of the bad data that they need to fix. Finally, we almost never have to rollback the load to prod because we did all the fixing before we went to prod. And the actual load to prod is faster (our prod is on a different server than our data processing server) because it does not have to do the cleaning steps at that point. Yes the overall import may take longer but the part that actually has the possibility to impact our customers takes less time.

We also have control over exactly what we do when something fails. For the most part (except for one particular type of import), we use a percentage (agreed on with the customer) of failed records to determine if the process has failed. This way 4 bad records in a million record file won't stop the process, but 100,000 will. And we have a few things that are showstoppers where even one bad record is a reason to stop the process. This gives us the freedom to determine on a case by case basis what we want  to use to stop the process.

Comment: +1 for "but we need to prove it". No one will ever believe that the transactional system produced junk until they see it with their own eyes. Our ETL is not as sophisticated but we take great pains to be able to trace any piece of data back to its original source.